# Application doesnot show in taskbar in windows 8

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8

I have an desktop application build on . Net 3.5 . Application is working properly in windows 7 and on XP as well. but in **windows 8** when I minimize my application it doesn't show in the task bar . please tell me how can i rectify this issue ?

Comment: Have you checked `ShowInTaskbar` property of the Main Form which is called from `Program.cs`?

Comment: brother its working fine windows 7 but not in windows 8. this is the issue

Comment: Dear may be it is related to your windows 8 taskbar settings or you have used `notifyicon` event to hide application in system tray, based on some scenario.

Comment: Are you loading form using ShowDialog method?